# mobile safari scroll page keyboard dismiss

Tags: ipad, events, dom, safari

We have an HTML5 webapp that needs to work on the iPad. The problem is that the page (body) scrolls up when the keyboard opens. When the keyboard is dismissed, the page remains in the scrolled up position. We need to detect the dismissal of the keyboard and scroll the page down. I have not been able to determine the event that would let me know that the user has dismissed the keyboard. We are using a WSIWIG Javascript-based HTML editor for editing content.

Answer (score 2):

After more investigation I learned that iPad Safari has issues with iframes. In our case the editing area was in an iFrame, thus the issue with page scrolling when keyboard was dismissed. When we eliminated the iframe the problem is solved.